# Unable to do fresh Linux install from CD

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, grub

I am using Windows 8 OS on my laptop and I had installed CentOS linux earlier. The BIOS is set for UEFI mode, thats why I had to switch it to legacy mode to support boot from CD.

Anyways, I managed to install CentOS clean the first time, but GRUB was not seeing Windows 8 as the second OS since, I wanted dual boot. So i tried messing around with the /etc/grub.conf file and now It wont even load windows.

I am tired of playing around, and i just want Linux to boot so I thought to re-install Linux again. So I deleted the Linux partition in my Windows 8 OS. Now its "Unallocated space". However when I put in the centOS 6 CD and try to boot from it, all i get is GRUB command line prompt.

I understand it is having trouble finding what to boot from CD, but then how did it do it the first time i installed it ? I am stuck with this :

grub>

There is no such thing as "ls" option. I am fairly new to Linux, so please pardon me if this question sounds dum. What do i do to have a fresh install of Linux ? Do i need to uninstall GRUB ?

Comment: Never Mind. I figured it out myself. The BIOS was not set to boot from CD (I know its stupid and I must have missed this), so in other words, the existing grub was actually the one on my hard drive trying to point to Linux which wasn't there since partition was deleted. Now that I have changed the boot priority to boot from CD a new GRUB will be installed along with a fresh OS install.

Comment: Thank you for posting your results, and the solution that ended up working.